# What is wrong with my program?? Basic C++

Tags: c++

My assignment says:

> ---Rewrite the program by grouping the calculations into functions. In particular, you should   introduce at least the following functions:
>
> ---A function named toLowerCase that takes a single character as an input parameter and returns a character. The returned value should be identical to the input unless the input is an upper-case letter, in which case the returned value should be the lower-case equivalent to that letter.
>
> ---Another function named toLowerCase, this one taking a string as an input parameter and returning a string. The returned string should be identical to the input except that all upper-case letters have been converted to lowercase.
>
> ----A function named readText that takes a string as an output parameter (no return value) and that reads multiple lines of input from cin until either hitting end-of-input or encountering an empty line. (Note: readText should not write anything to cout.)
>
> ----A function named countCharacter that takes two parameters as input and return an integer. The first input parameter will be a string and the second a character. The returned value should be the number of time that character occurs in the string (zero if the character occurs nowhere in the string). This function should work as described for all legal characters (i.e., even though this program will only use it to count lower-case letters, it should work for lower-case letters, upper-case letters, punctuation, etc.)
> As you introduce each function, replace the code in main() by calls to your new functions as appropriate.

I keep getting error: **expected primary-expression before char**

```
#include<iomanip>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

 void readText(string& text);
 void toLowercase(string& text);
 void countcharacter(string& text, char []);
 char ToLowerCase();


int main (int argc, char** argv)
{

  string userinput; //Initialize string name userinput

  cout << "Enter text to be analyzed, ending with an empty line or end-of-input:" <<     endl;

 readText(userinput); //Read text from user

cout << "You've entered: \n" << userinput << '\n'; // Read input, line by line, until end of input or an empty line

toLowercase(userinput); //Output user input and if upper-case, convert to lower-case

 cout << "Lower case version of what you said: \n" << userinput << '\n';

 countcharacter(userinput); //Count characters in userinput

 ToLowerCase();

  return 0;
}


void readText(string& text)
{

 string line;
 getline (cin, line);


while (cin && line != "")
{
  text = text + line + "\n";
  getline (cin, line);
}

 /*for(std::string line; getline(std::cin, line) && !'\n' ; )

    input += line + '\n'; */
}

void toLowercase(string& text)
{

  const int ucLcOffset = 'a' - 'A';
  for (int i = 0; i < text.size(); ++i)
{
  char c = text[i];
  if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
text[i] = text[i] + ucLcOffset;
}

}

void countcharacter(string& text, char c)
{
// Count and report on each alphabetic character
  int totalCount = 0;

  for (c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; ++c)
    {
  // Count how many times c occurs in the text
      int charCount = 0;
          for (int i = 0; i < text.size(); ++i)
       {
         if (text[i] == c)
         ++charCount;
       }
  // report on character c
      cout << c << ":" << charCount << " " << flush;
      if ((c - 'a') % 10 == 9)
    cout << "\n";
      totalCount = totalCount + charCount;
    }
 // How many characters are left over?
     cout << "\nother:" << text.size() - totalCount << endl;



}

char ToLowerCase()
{
    
 char c = 'A';
 char Conversion;
 const int ucLcOffset = 'a' - 'A';

     if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
    Conversion = c + ucLcOffset;

    cout << "Your conversion for character A is: " << Conversion << '\n';

}
```

Line 28 error. 'countcharacter(userinput); //Count characters in userinput'

Comment: Have you pointed out which line of code gives you the error?

Comment: do you mind telling us the line where the error occurs?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the faq. Homework questions are expected to be tagged as such.

Comment: line 28 error "countcharacter(userinput);

Comment: @Sam: What is the problem? What exactly do you need help with. It is unlikely that we will do you homework, but if you are nice we may point you in the correct direction.

Comment: How do I make a function that will take 2 inputs and return an integer, thats all. You can give me an example and I can figure it out from there

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
#inlcude<iostream>
```

Should be:

```
#include <iostream>
```

Syntax highlighting is your friend.

Also... `countcharacter()` takes two arguments:

```
void countcharacter(string& text, char []);
```

But you only provide one:

```
countcharacter(userinput);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#inlcude<iostream>
```

You spelt `include` wrong.

```
 countcharacter(userinput); //Count characters in userinput
```

`countcharacter()` takes two parameters, not one.

It seems you want to count the occurrences of each lower case character (`'a'`-`'z'`). In this case you don't need to pass a second argument to `countcharacter()`. Change:

```
void countcharacter(string& text, char []);
```

to

```
void countcharacter(string& text);
```

and

```
void countcharacter(string& text, char []);
```

to

```
void countcharacter(string& text);
```

You will also have to declare `char c` in `countcharacter()`.

It also seems you should change `char ToLowerCase()` to `void ToLowerCase()` as you don't seem to be returning anything.

Comment: no matter what parameter I put in there, I get the same error. Im trying to understand c++ and this is confusing me. I tried countcharacter(userinput, char c). Same error

Comment: Excellent! Exactly the same as my answer, but an extra upvote!

Comment: @Sam what is `countcharacter()` meant to do. It seems like it's meant to count the occurrences of a character but you call it as if you're trying to count the length of a string?

Comment: @quasiverse How can I change that. Yes I am trying to count the occurences of the specified character in the string. I'm kinda new and this is confusing

Comment: @Sam What character are you trying to count the occurrences of? I can't tell from your code.

Comment: @quasiverse, the letter 'c' then return by value. I dont understand functions very well and passing values between them. After I understand that, then I want to change it to whatever character is entered to be counted

Comment: @Sam Eugh... your code doesn't make any sense. If you only want to find the occurrences of `c` then why do you calculate it for all characters and how do you determine what character `c` is? You don't get it as input anywhere. Anyway, I've edited my answer. If you do all that, it'll work although maybe not how you wanted it...

Comment: @quasiverse I posted the assignment up top to avoid confusion. I have the code working that way, I have to convert it to the new way and cant figure it out

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a C++ guru, but the line

```
void countcharacter(string& text, char []);
```

Appears to be missing a parameter name.

Comment: right line, wrong reason. The declaration and definition differs, one is with "char[]" and other is with "char". Parameter name may be omitted in declaration, but argument  types in declaration and definition should be same.

Comment: Parameter names are optional, even more so in declarations. In definitions they are also optional, with the caveat that you cannot use them if you don't name them. It is usual to not name unused parameters to avoid compiler warnings about unused parameters.

Comment: Please explain a little more, I'm new to c++, still learning.

Comment: @osgx, there we go! I wasn't sure if they were, hence my qualification that I'm not much of a C++ guy.  Looks like a blind squirrel finds an acorn every once in a while ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Post the exact code you fed to your compiler.  You wouldn't get "error: expected primary-expression before char" for what you posted, you'd get "error: invalid preprocessing directive #inlcude".

Copy-and-paste it, don't re-type it.

**EDIT:** fixed errror message

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how they are different?

Comment: @K-ballo: My apologies, that was a copy-and-paste error on my part.  I've fixed it.  My point is that the original code (which I see has now been corrected) would not produce the error message the original poster indicated.

Comment: I fixed that, this is my first time on this website and was playing with it, code is updated now